# C# form X close and btnclose to function the same

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make the same functionality for form X (on the top extreme right) and close button. These 2 need to behave alike
This is what I have in btnClose_Click

```
     private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DialogResult result;
                int fileId = StaticClass.FileGlobal;
                if (DataDirty)
                {
                    string messageBoxText = "You have unsaved data. Do you want to save the changes and exit the form?";
                    MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                    string caption = "Data Changed";
                    MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
                    result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
                    if (result == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        Program.fInput = new frmInputFiles(gtId, gName);
                        Program.fInput.Show();
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        return;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.fInput = new frmInputFiles(gPlantId, gPlantName);
                    Program.fInput.Show();
                    this.Close();

                }

            }

    Even on clicking the X to close the form,it should behave the same way as btnClose_Click

      private void frmData_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {

        btnClose_Click(sender,e);//this doesnt seem to be working.
}
```

It is going in a infinite loop. I understand y it is doing that.. btnClose_Click() has this.Close() which calls frmData_FormClosing.. which inturn calls btnclose..

Thank u

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put this.Close() in the btnClose_Click() event. Then move all the rest of your logic (you'll need to edit it some) into the frmData_FormClosing() event and call `e.Cancel = true;` if you want to cancel closing the form (in your case, if there are unsaved changes and the user clicks Yes on the prompt.

Here's an example (I just cut and pasted in notepad, so fair warning):

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void frmData_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataDirty)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("You have unsaved data. Do you want to save the changes and exit the form?",
                            "Data Changed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Program.fInput = new frmInputFiles(gtId, gName);
            Program.fInput.Show();
        }
        else
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Program.fInput = new frmInputFiles(gPlantId, gPlantName);
        Program.fInput.Show();
    }
}
```